# How to get user's friends activities

Tags: facebook, api

I wonder how to get user's friend activities like Ticker on facebook [image]

Something like "XYZ post a new photo", "ABC commended in a post"
I see it work on api version 2.3 or lower using /me/home
But now it updated to 2.7. Can anyone show me how to get this infomation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the activities of friends. In fact, it is not possible to get ANY data of friends if they did not authorize your App. It is not even possible to get the activities of an autorized user.

Comment: I think with facebook graph api, you can get anything that you can see in your facebook newfeed,...

Comment: no, that is wrong, i´m afraid. what´s readable with the api is in the api reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/